# Can't Get Require Optimizer to mangle output

Tags: requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I'm using the Require Optimizer to combine all of our source files in to a single file.  That works great, but when I try to set `optimize: 'uglify'` or `optimze: 'uglify2'` I don't get mangled output: everything is combined in to a single line of a single file, but that line is filled with the original variable names.

I've tried setting various uglifyer options like:

```
uglify: {no_mangle: false}
```

or:

```
uglify2: {mangle: true}
```

but they don't work.  Can anyone explain how I can get the optimizer to mangle its output?

**EDIT**

Here's my `build.js` file:

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    paths: {
        template: 'ext/require/hbs',
        text: 'ext/require/text'
    },
    name: "main",
    optimize: "uglify",
    out: "../built/main-built.js",
    uglify: {
        beautify: false,
        space_colon: true,
        no_mangle: false,
    }
})
```

Comment: In my experience mangling happens by default. I would suggest trying to reproduce the problem you are encountering with a minimal set of files and putting it up for us to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up fixing this by updating our copy of Require.